# How to fix cursor issue with content editable attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

There is input field with `content editable`. Need to display block that contain `img` and none-displayable `span` with text. Snippet below did the task. But it has bug. And I can not change `contenteditable` because it belong external site and my code run in browser extension.

Run snippet. Click end of line, press left arrow button a few times. Your cursor moving through images to text. It's okay. Now press right arrow button and try to arrived end of line. When cursor get there first image, cursor's selection disappears. Another words, we can move cursor from right to left, but fail from left to right.

```css
.editor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">text <span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span></div>
```

If between images will any symbols, bug fix. But I need not symbols there. Because input field is message sender for chat where user can typing in any place.

I tried add pseudo element, bug still reproduce.

```css
span[contenteditable=false]:after {
    content: "space";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your issues is don't make the span tags  contenteditable="false"
make it true  contenteditable="true" so that the cursor issue will be solves

Comment: In this case will bugs with deleting and typing. You can change contenteditable and watch at dev inspector. So img and span must be entire, not breaks block.

Comment: i didn't get your point

Comment: Your recommendation fix cursor bug, but get other bugs with delete and type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">text <span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span></div>

The problem is your child spans are inheriting the contenteditable="true" from the parent div.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please correct your formatting. The text should be outside of, and preferably above the code block.

Comment: I checked property `contentEditable`: div (true) > span (false) > span(inherit) & img(inherit). So child span inheriting from parent span. Even if set false to all, bug reproduce.